# bootstrap nav link is not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm new here also newbie on ReactJS.

Here I created a navbar using bootstrap navbar component in Reactjs.

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg">
  <Container>
    <Navbar.Brand to={"/"}>Rental</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">

    <Nav>
      <Nav.Link to="/" >
         <FontAwesomeIcon 
          icon={faHome} 
       /> Home
     </Nav.Link>
     <Nav.Link to="/login" >
        <FontAwesomeIcon 
        icon={faUser} 
        /> Login/ Registration
     </Nav.Link>
  </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
 </Container>
</Navbar>
```

When I go Browser and Check It shows like this:

```
<a to="/" role="button" class="nav-link" tabindex="0">Home</a>
```

and the link won't working.

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you use React router. React does not come with its own routing solution and recommends to use react-router for routing.

Comment: Yes I use reactjs router

Comment: `<a to="/" role="button" class="nav-link" tabindex="0">Home</a>` It won't be button but it shows as button I think thats why link not working and to isn't change yet it will be `href` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're rendering react-bootstrap's Nav.Link instead of react-router's Link component, so the router is not picking up your route changes.

So importing Link from react router and using it should fix the issue.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" >
   <FontAwesomeIcon 
      icon={faHome} 
    /> Home
</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: it works now thanks @Shaurya Vardhan Singh

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a Router, make sure that you're doing that inside App or in ReactDOM.render:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>, 
  rootElement
  );
```

You're rendering react-bootstrap's Nav.Link instead of react-router's Link component, so the router is not picking up your route changes.

react-bootstrap provides a render prop in most of its components to specify which component or element we want to render if we don't want the default.

Try to make these changes!

```
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
<Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/" >Rental</Navbar.Brand>
```

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" >
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome}/>
        Home
</Nav.Link>
```

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/login" >
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser}/> 
        Login/ Registration
</Nav.Link>
```